# divide string in to 3 parts, first 2 words as words and last as mixed words

Tags: javascript

A descriptive title was not easy to write so I will explain more what I am trying to do here.
I have a chatroom script and server-side I am creating commands that users can type in to chat etc
/report username reason
Of course when the string arrives at the server it looks something like this '/report Tim for abusing chat' or '/report John because he likes to post annoying links'
I can grab /report, username and 1st word of reason by using the following code.

```
var string = MessageString;
var temp = string.split(" ");
var CommandOne = temp[0];
var CommandTwo = temp[1];
var CommandThree = temp[2];
```

The problem is the last part of the string, how can I grab everything for the reason section which is after the 2nd word in the string? CommandOne will show /report, CommandTwo will show the users name but CommandThree will only show the first word for the reason and not the whole reason.
I have also been trying to use the following code but can not quite get it to work right.

```
var original = MessageString;
var result = original.substr(original.indexOf(" ") + 1);
var CommandThree = result.substr(result.indexOf(" ", "") + 1);
```

I looked at the similar posts on here but could not find any which did this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `slice` to get all the remaining words, and join them back together into a string:

```
var string = MessageString;
var temp = string.split(" ");
var CommandOne = temp[0];
var CommandTwo = temp[1];
var CommandThree = temp.slice(2).join(" ");
```

Comment: they all worked but could not click solved for all of them but I am grateful for your help lads, I did struggle with this for sometime but put it off to the last moment. I love this site, awesome

Answer (score 1):

Robin Zigmond beat me to the punch. slice is the way to go.

```js
const message = '/report Tim for abusing chat';
const words = message.split(' ');
const action = words[0];
const username = words[1];
const reason = words.slice(2).join(' ');
console.log('action:', action);
console.log('username:', username);
console.log('reason:', reason);
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can try the following

```
var string = MessageString;
var temp = string.split(" ");

var CommandOne = temp.shift();
var CommandTwo = temp.shift();
var CommandThree = temp.join(" ");
```